# Body of rotation's volume equals 0 when calculated without expansion

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

Recently, I was working on exercises concerning bodies of rotation, when I ran into an issue with calculating a value for some of these.

The exercise goes as follows (I'm paraphrasing):
Consider a function $f(x)=x^2-4$. Calculate the volume of the body created when the area defined by $f(x)$ and the x-axis is rotated around the x-axis.

The beginning is straightforward enough. I calculate the intersections of $f(x)$ with the x-axis, which gives me $x_1=-2$ and $x_2=2$. These are the boundaries for my integral.

I can now determine the integral for further calculations:

$$
V=\pi *\int_{-2}^{2}(x^2 - 4)^2 dx
$$

This is where problems start appearing. If I continue by finding the antiderivative of $(x^2-4)^2$, I get this:

$$
V=\pi*\left[\frac{1}{6x}(x^2-4)^3\right]_{-2}^2
$$
$$
V=\pi\left(\frac{1}{6(2)}((2)^2 - 4)^3 - \frac{1}{6(-2)}((-2)^2 - 4)^3\right)
$$
$$
V=\pi(0 - 0) = 0
$$

This is obviously incorrect. However, if I instead use apply the binomial rule and turn $(x^2-4)^2$ into $x^4 - 8x^2 + 16$, I can perform these calculations:

$$
V=\pi*\left[\frac15x^5 - \frac83x^3 + 16x\right]_{-2}^2
$$
$$
V=\pi\left(\frac15(2)^5 - \frac83(2)^3 + 16(2) - \left(\frac15(-2)^5 - \frac83(-2)^3 + 16(-2)\right)\right)
$$
$$
V=\pi\left(\frac{256}{15} - \frac{-256}{15}\right) = \frac{512}{15}\pi
$$

This appears to be the correct answer (there may be an arithmetic error). This leads me to wonder: Why does expanding the equation lead to the correct result, while not doing so give $0$? I can see why in the function itself (if I carry over the part of the equation I originally set equal to $0$, of course the results from that in the same function will give me $0$), but it doesn't make intuitive sense to me. Any help explaining this is appreciated! (I believe it has something to do with antiderivatives)

Comment: Your first attempt at antidifferentiation was wrong. You seemed to be thinking that there was a chain rule for the process. Not so. The *only* way to do it is to expand.

Comment: However, if I derive the resulting function, I receive the original, which is the definition of the antiderivative. If you know more about why this isn't possible, perhaps post an answer?

Comment: @Light Drake https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+(x%5E2-4)%5E3%2F(6x) you don't get back the original function when you take the derivative of your first expression.

Comment: Oh ****. Just noticed that I can't just ignore the $6x$ outside of the parenthesis when taking the derivative. I'll post an answer tomorrow, it's quite late here.

Answer (score 1):

So, as @Lubin and @Tyberius have pointed out, the first antiderivative is incorrect, as I was previously ignoring the $\frac1{6x}$ factor I added to the antiderivative, which must of course also be derived using the product rule $(u * v)' = u' * v + u * v'$, leading to a different function in the end:

$$
\frac{(-4 + x^2)^2 (4 + 5 x^2)}{6 x^2}
$$

This falsified my later calculations.